# JMS send same message back to SQS

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am working on an approach where i am required to send a message back to SQS.
I don't want it to go as a new message as that will reset the **approximateRecieveCount** parameter which is required by the code.

Please note that
**I cannot send a NACK to the queue as i am reading it as a batch of 10 messages, I want to manually post it back in certain cases for individual message and not as a batch.**

The code I am trying to use

I tried setting the JMSMessageId but it is not possible as according to the documentation -

> After you send messages, Amazon SQS sets the following headers and properties for each message:
>
> 1. JMSMessageID
> 2. JMS_SQS_SequenceNumber (only for FIFO queues)

The code i am using right now is

```
    defaultJmsTemplate.send(destinationName, new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            Message message = session.createTextMessage(errorMessage);
            message.setJMSCorrelationID(transactionId);

            if (destinationName.endsWith(".fifo")) {
                message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", property.getMessageGroup());
                message.setStringProperty("JMS_SQS_DeduplicationId", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }

            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

Is there anything that i can set/use to make sure the message is not treated as a new message and the approximate receive count is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This can be done. As you are using JMS for SQS while setting up your consumer you can define an `UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode in your consumer session. By doing so if you do not acknowledge a particular message it will be redelivered after its visibility timeout expires and the `approximateRecieveCount` will be incremented. This will not impact your other messages in the same batch. One downside of this is if you are using the fifo queue and the all your messages have same group id then you next message will only be processed after this `unacknowledged` message ends up in dead letter queue. This will only happen after your message is retried for the `Maximum Receives` that you have set up in fifo queue configuration. Note : The key here is to not `acknowledge` a particular message.